# what difference bewteen binding and internalBinding in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Recently,I am reading node.js source code. In lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js I found a function named 'internalBinding()'. And I know binding is for bridge C++ and JS, what internalBinding() do? What is the difference between binding and internalBinding?

```
const {
  internalModuleReadJSON,
  internalModuleStat
} = internalBinding('fs');
const { safeGetenv } = internalBinding('credentials');
```